# Remove all text after 3 word - Excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a large CSV file, where one field contains a huge list of words in the following format

word 1, word 2, word 3, word 4, word 5, word 6  and so

What formula could I use to keep the first 3 words and delete everything after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options; one is `SUBSTITUTE` to change the 3rd comma to some other character, and then `LEFT` and `FIND` to retain only everything beforehand:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",3))-1)
```

[image]